# mediaelement.js dont work in ios after infinite-scroll

Tags: ios, ajax, mediaelement.js, infinite-scroll, jquery-isotope

I made some media items(video,audio) by mediaelement.js in a list page with infinite-scroll and isotope jquery plugin. I use the infinite-scroll for going next page. it's a ajax plugin. There is a viedo item(c1) in first page and a audio item(c2) in second page. When scroll to bottom, the second page(c2 audio item) will be loaded.
The problem is when the page is runing in ipad and iphone, when infinite-scroll the second page, the c1 video can't be played, it's always loading. It works fine in firefox and chrome of pc. Please help me to check the codes.
[(This's the link.)](http://www.uiueux.com/test3211/h5player/test-h5plyer.html)

Answer (score 0):

**I got the answer.**

this codes will be ok, hope to help somebody:

```
jQuery(newElements).find('audio,video').mediaelementplayer();
```